# postgres value too long for type character varying(100)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I created a flask website with Postgres database. I created a class like this.

```
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False)
    summary = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False)
```

However, when I tried to "add" a book with a summary field. There is a error like this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(100)

[SQL: INSERT INTO books (id, title, summary, image) VALUES (%(id)s, %(title)s, %(summary)s, %(image)s)]
[parameters: {'id': 5, 'title': 'Crying in H Mart: A Memoir', 'summary': "In this exquisite story of family, food, grief, and endurance, Michelle Zauner proves herself far more than a dazzling singer, songwriter, and guitar ... (218 characters truncated) ... treasured months spent in her grandmother's tiny apartment in Seoul, where she and her mother would bond, late at night, over heaping plates of food.", 'image': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51gNCTAbLJS.jpg'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)
192.168.0.15 - - [15/May/2022 10:09:33] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried summary = db.Column(db.String(10000), unique=False)

and summary = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False)
and summary = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)

But none of them work....

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to add a book called "Crying in H Mart" with some summary. looks like the summary got 218 characters truncated.

Comment: Check your actual table schema in `psql`. If the table already exists, it won't be recreated. Also, don't put limits on columns which don't have limits; you're not saving any space. Use `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your table already exists from a previous run of the program. [SQLAlchemy `create_all` will not recreate nor change an existing table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables).

> The usual way to issue CREATE is to use create_all() on the MetaData object. This method will issue queries that first check for the existence of each individual table, and if not found will issue the CREATE statements:

So your changes to the schema in the code have no effect if the table already exists.

While experimenting you can simply [`drop_all`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.drop_all) to clear the schema and then `create_all`. All tables will be recreated.

If you want to preserve the data you'd [write a migration](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) to alter the existing table.

---

In general, don't put artificial limits on columns. It doesn't save any space. In Postgres, use `text`.